# how to get an svg to replace the weather text in a react functional component

Tags: reactjs

React gods! I'm trying to make a weather app and  I've been able to render out the text saying what the weather is, but I now want to have an svg of the weather to show up. Im not sure how to go about making it work in functional component. heres what I got so far. I was thinking if theres a way to put all the svgs into variables it would work with string concatenation, or just use if then or switch statements.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const api = {
  key:"dbe4e6036b179b241f68b078f58c0c5a",
  base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
}

function Data() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  const search = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=imperial&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
          setWeather(result); 
          setQuery('');
          console.log(result)
        })
    }

  }

  return (
    <div className="weatherApp">
      <main> 
        <div className="searchBox">
        <input 
          type="text" 
          className="searchBar" 
          placeholder= "How's the weather in..."
          onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}
          value={query}
          onKeyPress={search}
        />
        </div>
        {(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? (
        <div>
          <div className="weather-box">
            <div className="temp">
            {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}°F
            </div>
            <div className="weather">
              {weather.weather[0].main}
            </div>
           <Date />

          <div className="location-box">
            <div className='location'>{weather.name}</div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : ('')}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: svg in react can be used like you would use it in a normal html. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

React allows you to import SVGs as components via:

```
import {ReactComponent as Hot} from '../path-to-hot.svg'
import {ReactComponent as Cold} from '../path-to-cold.svg'
import {ReactComponent as Rain} from '../path-to-rain.svg'

///This allows you to use the svgs as a component

export default function Weather({weather}){
    
    // I think just creating a mapping of the text to a component is enough. 
    //A switch statement would also do well here 
   
    const weatherMap = {
    hot: <Hot/>,
    cold: <Cold/>,
    rain: <Rain/>   
    }
    
    const currWeather = weatherMap[weather]
    
    return <>{currWeather}</>
}
```